# How to interface .NET application with Alfresco using dotCMIS

Tags: asp.net, alfresco, vb.net-2010, dotcmis

How to interface .NET application with Alfresco using dotCMIS.

I checked on Apache chemistry site. But, did not get all details like "how to set web.config file, where we put Service reference folder, where we create end point and which files do we have to put on bin and all ". please update me if you guys any one know it.

Comment: don't know if there's a difference between working with .net and java but i think it's the same

Comment: If you're connecting to Alfresco from .Net, you don't need to create any service files or create endpoints, those are all server-side and done by Alfresco already

Comment: Thanks for Update. I did not connect to Alfresco through .NET application.   Please update me, how to connect to Alfresco through .NET application?.

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr, I gave wrong Autopub URL. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate/interface a .NET application with Alfresco with the Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) standard. These APIs allow you to perform various content management and business process management tasks, such as document retrieval, workflow management, and user authentication...

You can use this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/surya_bg2000/alfresco-integration-with-net-using-cmis/) to learn more how to use the library.